# How to reduce CPU utilization in file compare algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, file, compare

I have got about 2000 files to be compared against each other, let's forget about the technical platform. This should ideally result in 2000*1999/2 , which is 1999000 comparisons, which will result in enormous amount of CPU consumption. Is there an alternate way? Merging all the files, and making a big file, and comparing the 2000 files with this big merge is something that is being thought and tried out. All the redundant pairs are already being eliminated.

Any high level thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you comparing them for, are you eliminating duplicates?

Comment: That's gonna depend on how you compare them and your similarity metric.

Comment: I am comparing them for text matches, using a line compare utility provided by the OS that I work on. Duplicates, redundancies, and self compares are already eliminated. The average file size is 1000 KB, and I have 2000 such files.

Comment: Why don't you compare the [digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)? You can use an hash function

Comment: Define "text matches", if you are looking for exact copy it is as simple as hash(file) and compare files with identical hash values only. If you are looking for something more complex (like near duplicates detection), that's going to depend on the exact metric you are using.

Comment: Thank you all, My requirement is to compare the files, and get the percentage of bytes matched, for all the nCn combinations.